# Jquery OnLoad - weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, onload

I have this function:

```
$("#loading_button").click(function(){
    (function() {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
       s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.async = true;
        s.src = '//some_src/';
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.onload = function() {
            alert("OK");
            $('#my_button').trigger('click');
        };
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
});
```

With the alert there, all works fine. #my_button from the src script is clicked automatically. The problem is that as soon as I remove the alert(), trigger, click trigger is not called anymore.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

try not to call your code directly, but bind it to document.ready instead;

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // <-- look here
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = '//some_src/';
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.onload = function() {
        alert("OK");
        $('#my_button').trigger('click');
    };
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
}); // <-- and here
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks! The problem is that I need to load that JS file on button click, I edited my question to show this.: